# SQLite split column on another column's value

Tags: sql, sqlite, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have a database in which multiple variables appear as consecutive rows (shown below, variables differentiated by their tags). As a result, their values appear as consecutive rows in the 'value' column.

Existing table:

[image: Existing table]

For data analysis, I need to split each variable's value into separate columns, as illustrated below.

[image: Desired layout]

The SQLite query is listed below. I have tried using GROUP BY tag and averaging the values, but the result becomes too granular to be useful.

Advice would be much appreciated!

```
SELECT
        tag
        ,time
        ,value
FROM 
    [archive]..[interp]
WHERE 
    tag 
IN
    ( 'flow1.Val'           
     , 'flow2.Val'
     , 'density1.Val' 
     , 'density2.Val'
     )
  
AND 
    time 
BETWEEN 
    't-1d' and 't'
AND 
    timestep = '1h'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select time,
    max(case when tag = 'flow1.Val' then value end) as flow1_val,
    max(case when tag = 'flow2.Val' then value end) as flow2_val,
    max(case when tag = 'density1.Val' then value end) as density1_val,
    max(case when tag = 'density2.Val' then value end) as density2_val
from [archive]..[interp]
group by time
```

Depending on your actual requirement, you might want to use another aggregate function than `max()`, it you have more than one row for a given time/tag tuple.